# Extending CSS selectors in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, css-selectors, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, lxml.html

**The Question:**

`BeautifulSoup` provides a *very limited support for [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)*. For instance, the only supported pseudo-class is `nth-of-type` and it can only accept numerical values - arguments like `even` or `odd` are not allowed.

Is it possible to extend `BeautifulSoup` CSS selectors or let it use [`lxml.cssselect`](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html) internally as an underlying CSS selection mechanism?

---

Let's take a look at an **example problem/use case**. Locate only even rows in the following HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In `lxml.html` and `lxml.cssselect`, it is easy to do via `:nth-of-type(even)`:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector

tree = fromstring(data)

sel = CSSSelector('tr:nth-of-type(even)')

print [e.text_content().strip() for e in sel(tree)]
```

But, in `BeautifulSoup`:

```
print(soup.select("tr:nth-of-type(even)"))
```

would throw an error:

> NotImplementedError: Only numeric values are currently supported for the nth-of-type pseudo-class.

---

Note that we can workaround it with [`.find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all):

```
print([row.get_text(strip=True) for index, row in enumerate(soup.find_all("tr"), start=1) if index % 2 == 0])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After checking the source code, it seems that `BeautifulSoup` does not provide any convenient point in its interface to extend or monkey patch its existing functionality in this regard. Using functionality from `lxml` is not possible either since `BeautifulSoup` only uses `lxml` during parsing and uses the parsing results to create its own respective objects from them. The `lxml` objects are not preserved and cannot be accessed later.

That being said, with enough determination and with the flexibility and introspection capabilities of Python, anything is possible. You can modify the BeautifulSoup method internals even at run-time:

```py
import inspect
import re
import textwrap

import bs4.element


def replace_code_lines(source, start_token, end_token,
                       replacement, escape_tokens=True):
    """Replace the source code between `start_token` and `end_token`
    in `source` with `replacement`. The `start_token` portion is included
    in the replaced code. If `escape_tokens` is True (default),
    escape the tokens to avoid them being treated as a regular expression."""

    if escape_tokens:
        start_token = re.escape(start_token)
        end_token = re.escape(end_token)

    def replace_with_indent(match):
        indent = match.group(1)
        return textwrap.indent(replacement, indent)

    return re.sub(r"^(\s+)({}[\s\S]+?)(?=^\1{})".format(start_token, end_token),
                  replace_with_indent, source, flags=re.MULTILINE)


# Get the source code of the Tag.select() method
src = textwrap.dedent(inspect.getsource(bs4.element.Tag.select))

# Replace the relevant part of the method
start_token = "if pseudo_type == 'nth-of-type':"
end_token = "else"
replacement = """\
if pseudo_type == 'nth-of-type':
    try:
        if pseudo_value in ("even", "odd"):
            pass
        else:
            pseudo_value = int(pseudo_value)
    except:
        raise NotImplementedError(
            'Only numeric values, "even" and "odd" are currently '
            'supported for the nth-of-type pseudo-class.')
    if isinstance(pseudo_value, int) and pseudo_value < 1:
        raise ValueError(
            'nth-of-type pseudo-class value must be at least 1.')
    class Counter(object):
        def __init__(self, destination):
            self.count = 0
            self.destination = destination

        def nth_child_of_type(self, tag):
            self.count += 1
            if pseudo_value == "even":
                return not bool(self.count % 2)
            elif pseudo_value == "odd":
                return bool(self.count % 2)
            elif self.count == self.destination:
                return True
            elif self.count > self.destination:
                # Stop the generator that's sending us
                # these things.
                raise StopIteration()
            return False
    checker = Counter(pseudo_value).nth_child_of_type
"""
new_src = replace_code_lines(src, start_token, end_token, replacement)

# Compile it and execute it in the target module's namespace
exec(new_src, bs4.element.__dict__)
# Monkey patch the target method
bs4.element.Tag.select = bs4.element.select
```

[This](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/element.py#L1374) is the portion of code being modified.

Of course, this is everything but elegant and reliable. I don't envision this being seriously used anywhere, ever.

Comment: Thanks for the strong `I don't envision this being seriously used anywhere, ever.`! :)

Answer (score 4):

Officially, **Beautifulsoup** doesn't support all the CSS selectors.

If python is not the only choice, i strongly recommend **JSoup** (the java equivalent of this). It supports all the CSS selectors.

- It is open source (MIT license)
- Syntax is easy
- Supports all the css selectors
- Can span multiple threads too to scale up
- Rich API support in java to store in DBs. So, it is easy to integrate.

The other alternate way if you still want to stick with python, make it a jython implementation.

http://jsoup.org/

https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/