# Read and modify a the code of a python script from another python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, full-text-search, traversal

Is there any package in python that can read a python script and give the ability to modify it? Something like the following:

```py
my_script: PythonScript = read_script("my_script.py")
list_of_functions: [PythonFunction] = my_script.functions
for func in list_of_functions:
   print(func.name)
   print(func.body)
list_of_functions[0].name = "new_function_name"
my_script.functions = list_of_functions
```

So again what I am looking for is a package that can read a python script and give the ability to modify it, not necessary the same way I did in my example, I just have a lot of scripts and I am looking for a way to do a fix on all of them without using find and replace in an IDE nor reading them as text files for example. 
Somehow traversing a python script from python code? I do not know what keywords should I use to do a proper search either.

Comment: Looks like there are similar question here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41858147/how-to-modify-imported-source-code-on-the-fly, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/how-to-list-all-functions-in-a-python-module , I think you can play around with inspect to solve your problem

Comment: I am not looking for modifying imported packages. But I will give it a look maybe I can get some ideas

Comment: you just need list of the functions ?

Comment: No, I need to also have the code of the function, and to be able to modify it as well. Maybe there is nothing like this since this a very rare problem?